# How to return a variable by reference in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, reference, return

This is my code:

```
function &query_test(....)
{
  $ret = array(....);
  return ($ret);
}
```

Why do I get a strict warning on PHPStorm saying
"Only variables can be returned by reference"

I have tried creating $ret as an element of the class and using return($this->ret)
tried using return(&$ret);
tried using return (new $ret);

I have another piece of code in another file, that doesn't complain.  I can't find any difference in the code as to why one complains and the other doesn't.  Is it possible the other file is telling PHPStorm not to complain.  both files are in the same project, same directory.

I have read a lot of posts about this.  although a google search for the complaint gives a lot of posts about passing variables by reference, not returning a reference to a variable.

The code works.  my call the the function is

```
$result = $obj->query_test(....);
```

I understand that maybe I should be using

```
$result =& $obj->query_test(...);
```

If I do the latter what are the ramifications?

I would like to get rid of the strict message in PHPStorm., by fixing the code.
The array being returned can by quite a large piece of data.
Removing the & from the function definition is not an option as the base class this class is derived from has the same function name with the &.  The base class in another file doesn't complain.  Weird, I must be missing something.

See problem details for what I have tried.

Comment: Yes, you are trying to solve a non-existent problem. Such as "The array being returned can by quite a large piece of data". Do you have any *particular* problem with this piece of data?

Comment: `Why do I get a strict warning on PHPStorm saying "Only variables can be returned by reference"`. That is not a PHPStorm error message. That comes from PHP itself, just passed thru.

Comment: I found the problem.   return ($ret);  and return $ret;  are not the same.  The first is an expression, the second is not.